# what is a doubly linked list - Java?

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures

I am currently learning algorithms using Java, and just started to learn java doubly linked list algorithm. partially I understood the concept behind it, however i fully understood the singly linked list.

In a singly linked list, the linkedList class will always remember the link that came last to the list where as all the other links that came before the last link will remember the reference for their previous links one after another.

as i understood what the doublylist does here is that they remember the both next and previous links of the list. But when it comes to implementation it is hard to understand. for example i am completely confused when thinking about how to add new links for the tail or the head.

can any one explain what actually a doubly linkedlist is.
if then can you provide a sample code.

Comment: Not the *last*, the *next*.

Comment: Have you read the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doubly_linked_list)?

Comment: While this is a valid question, questions regarding tutorials are considered off-topic in this site. Please take the [tour], and see [ask].

Comment: No I did not...but is there some real world example for explaining this

Comment: There are even [animations online](https://www.codelike.in/animation/doubly-linked-list). A doubly linked list is a singly linked list where each node hasn't only a link to the next node but also to the previous one. So you can traverse the list both ways.

Comment: @jrook I tend to disagree. There are really zillions of resources out there explaining the concept of (double) linked lists. In all detail. This question really lacks prior research.

Comment: I just asked a real world example @GhostCat

Comment: *can any one explain what actually a doubly linkedlist is* ... and you accepted an answer that didnt give an example. As said. the point is that you are expected to do **serious** research prior asking a question. This community is not a replacement for you sitting down and doing that "learning" part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A line of children, each with one hand on the shoulder of the child in front of them, is a linked-list. Each child knows the child ahead of them, but cannot know about the child behind them. In Java, each element in the list has **a single member** for the reference of the next element.

In a line of children holding hands, each knows both the child ahead *and* the child behind. So a double-linked list. In Java, each element has ***two* members** for the references of the element ahead and the element behind.

---

Inserting an element involves changing four references.

1. Set the leading element’s “looking back” reference to point to the new element.
2. The new element’s “looking forward” reference is set to point to that leading element.
3. And you change the trailing element’s “looking forward” reference to point to the new element.
4. The new element’s “looking back” reference is set to point to that trailing element.

---

The content, or payload, of each element is an object laying somewhere else in memory. Each element carries a pointer to its payload object.

So a doubly-linked list is simply **a series of triple-pointers** (references). The first and last element each have one of their 3 pointers set to null.

---

All is this [explained in Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doubly_linked_list). Always study Wikipedia before posting here.

Comment: That's some ELI5!